# Is it possible to create a Trello "template" or simply duplicate a board?

Tags: trello

I'd like to create Trello templates that can serve as a reusable starting point for projects. Is it possible to "copy and paste" an entire board?

it would come in very handy if there was a posibility to create templates for cards and lists too.

and it would help if it was on "global" level (board overview) and that can be activated withing the boards/projects if used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, creating Trello 'templates' or duplication of a board is possible since this post: http://blog.trello.com/you-can-copy-boards-now-finally/

The [Trello help page on copying](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/980926-copying-cards-boards-or-lists) mentions how to do that.

For more background information, there is an [earlier help page in Trello on templates](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/981011-creating-templates-for-cards-lists-and-boards), and the [original Trello card for this feature](https://trello.com/card/copy-boards-cards-and-checklists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/961).

Comment: Try to style your answer a bit. It looks like all hyperlinks....

Comment: Done. It looked like all hyperlinks because it is almost all hyperlinks :-) which also makes it easier to see where the link will direct you. Let's see whether this is more useful.

Answer (score 4):

Copying boards is not currently possible. Board templates are also not currently available.

Comment: Any chance it will happen in the future?

Comment: You can follow along at https://trello.com/card/board/templates-for-boards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e6fdc349d5bce0000004fa6